# Sort threads within a specific forum by the latest activity

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

forums, threads, comments

I would like to sort all threads within a specific forum, considering the time the thread was posted and the last comment posted within threads.

Every row in threads has a column "fid" which shows which forum the thread was posted in.

Every row in comments has a column "tid" which shows which thread the comment was posted on.

What is the right query to get it done?

Edit:

Structure:

forums - id, name

threads - id, fid (forum id), title, time

comments - id, tid (thread id), content, time

I would like the threads to be shown in this order, for example:

```
THREAD - POSTED 10 MINUTES AGO - LAST COMMENT 6 MINUTE AGO
THREAD - POSTED 11 MINUTES AGO - NO COMMENTS
THREAD - POSTED 20 MINUTES AGO - LAST COMMENT 13 MINUTES AGO
```

I have tried this so far:

```
SELECT * FROM threads INNER JOIN comments ON  threads.id = comments.tid WHERE threads.fid = 3
GROUP BY threads.id ORDER BY MAX(comments.time)  DESC
```

Comment: Could you provide the structure of each table?

Comment: @Wistar Sure, I edited the question.

Comment: If you want to sort by time you need to have to have a timestamp in your thread and comments tables.

Comment: @Wistar Yes, I do have it, sorry. I'll re-edit.

Comment: Finally, you should give an exemple of the expected result and what you have tried so far

Comment: @Wistar Edited again, hope that is good enough

Comment: Your table names in your query do not match the table name in the structure you provided. Plus, you use `{$fid}` which is undefined.

Comment: @Wistar It is the same tables,  I have shorten it so it would be more comfortable for you.. I will change it again... Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT `t`.`id`, `t`.`title`, `t`.`time`, `c`.`comment_time`  
FROM `threads` t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `tid`, MAX(`time`) AS comment_time FROM `comments` GROUP BY  `tid`) c
ON `t`.`id` = `c`.`tid`
ORDER BY `t`.`time`, `c`.`comment_time` desc
```

Comment: When I order by     `c`.`comment_time` it works fine but threads with no comments go to the bottom. When I leave it the way you wrote it, it sorts the threads by their date but won't consider comments.